# Add firebase ui with script tag

Tags: firebase, vue.js, single-page-application

I develop a spa with nuxt. I try to add firebase ui to the project. I use the instruction on github

In the head, I put this in the head

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/3.5.2/firebase-ui-auth__vi.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/3.5.2/firebase-ui-auth.css" />`

In FirebaseAuth.vue

`const app = firebase.initializeApp(config)
const auth = app.auth()
export const ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(auth)`

I got this erro
`'firebaseui' is not defined`

https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#localized-widget

Comment: with nuxt you need to install things as npm packages so node can actually require them

Comment: I use cdn because firebaseui doesn't have localization for npm packages. Just cdn

Comment: YOU CANT USE IT!

Comment: what do you mean?